# Realizar un trigger de historial

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

necesito ayuda para realizar un trigger de delete y almacenarlo en una tabla para tener como si fuera una especie de Historial.

Tengo la tabla producto donde tengo una serie de campos, y la tabla baja donde se lanzaría el trigger y guardaria los datos que se han eliminado en producto que pasara a la tabla baja.

Este es el trigger que he probado:

```
create trigger productoHistorialEliminado ON producto for Delete As
    insert into baja select *,GetDate() from deleted;
```

Pero la tabla `deleted` no existe en mi bd. Pero esa tabla es interna del sistema, ¿no?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Comparte lo que tienes intentado hasta el momento para que los usuarios te puedas ayudar mejor :)

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el [tour] de bienvenida. Deberías [edit] tu pregunta para añadir los detalles en ella, en lugar de usar la zona de respuestas para ello.

Comment: Sobre que base de datos estas trabajando?

Comment: MySQL Community Server version 8.0.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Propongo que tu trigger tenga la siguiente estructura:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER nombreTrigger BEFORE DELETE ON tablaOrigen
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tablaDestino(nombre, email, edad)
        VALUES
        (old.userName, old.userEmail, old.userEdad);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

- Le asignas un nombre al trigger
- Le indicas que su ejecución **ocurra antes de eliminar** en la **tablaorigen** (esta tabla es de la cual vas a eliminar)
- Después de la sentencia **`BEGIN`** indicas el **`INSERT INTO`** pero ahora apuntando a la **tablaDestino que es donde se almacenarán los valores borrados**
- Agrega las columnas que sean necesarias, es decir aquellas que quieres almacenar de la fila que piensas eliminar en la tabla origen (esto lo verificas con `DESCRIBE` de tu tabla destino o donde se almacenarán los registros borrados)
- Para el caso de la palabra reservada **`OLD`** en la [doc. de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) nos indica que solo se puede usar cuando se hace uso de **`DELETE`**
- Toma en cuenta que los valores que van precedidos de **`old`** son los nombres de las columnas de la tabla origen de la cual quieres eliminar, por lo que dichos nombres deberán estar escritos de forma idéntica

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio :)

Comment: @BetaM me gusto mucho la manera en como explicas, tengo un problema con trigger, bueno a seguir intentando resolver