# consultas con triggers

Tags: sql, postgresql

Crear un Trigger que se ejecute cada vez que se modifique un registro en la tabla payments,
almacenando en una tabla de auditoria los siguientes atributos: nombre del atributo
modificado, valor actual dela tributo, nuevo valor del atributo, usuario que hace la
modificación y fecha de la modificación.

alguno me puede ayudar

```
        Create table aud_Pago (ant_customernumber
integer, ant_checknumber varchar(50),
ant_paymentdate timestamp, ant_amount float,
act_customernumber integer, act_checknumber
varchar(50), act_paymentdate timestamp,
act_amount float, usuario varchar(20) default user,
fecha timestamp default now());

create function fun_auditaPago() returns trigger
as
$$
begin
insert into aud_Pago (ant_customernumber, ant_checknumber,
ant_paymentdate, ant_amount, act_customernumber,
act_checknumber, act_paymentdate, act_amount) values
(old.customernumber, old.checknumber, old.paymentdate,
old.amount, new.customernumber, new.checknumber,
new.paymentdate, new.amount);
return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger tri_audiPayment after update
on payments
for each row
execute procedure fun_auditaPago();
```

Comment: ¿qué has intentado?, lee [ask]

Comment: ¿Responde a esto tu pregunta?: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/319351/realizar-un-trigger-de-historial/319384#319384

Comment: debo crear otra tabala que me almacene como el historial de los cambios que si hicieron en esa tabla payments?

Comment: tengo algo pero no se si sera asi

Comment: Agrega lo que tengas

Comment: el código va en la pregunta

Comment: cree otra tabla pero no se si estoy seguro esto responda mi pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que tu tabla de **texto en negrita**payments**texto en negrita** sea parecida a la que sigue. Solo tienes que cambiar **after** por **before** en el trigger:

````
customernumber int, 
checknumber varchar(50), 
paymentdate timestamp,
amount float);

create trigger tri_audiPayment before update
on payments
for each row
execute procedure fun_auditaPago();```
````